# connect to rethinkdb running in docker kitematic

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

I'm trying to set up a local rethinkdb on a docker container using [kitematic](https://kitematic.com/). However, the connection always times out (`RqlDriverError: Handshake timedout`). Is there additional setup that I need to do to? Any other advice is appreciated!

Rethinkdb container is running on the following ports:

```
(Docker port --> Mac port)
8080  --> 192.168.99.100:49155
28015 --> 192.168.99.100:49153
29015 --> 192.168.99.100:49154
```

Here's my setup:

```
r.connect({
  host: '192.168.99.100'
, port: 49155
, timeout: 10
}, function dbConnect (err, conn) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  else {
    console.log('ahoy!')
  }
})
```

Comment: Client drivers should connect to the client driver port, which is 28015 by default, which maps to 49153 in your case.

Comment: Tried that and got a different error: 

`RqlDriverError: Server dropped connection with message: "ERROR: Received an unsupported protocol version. This port is for RethinkDB queries. Does your client driver version not match the server?"`

So then I updated the driver version running in docker; works now. Thanks!

Comment: same her. Im using python. My client driver version is rethinkdb==2.0.0-2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your client driver version is different from your server driver version. You have to update both